# Overriding start_requests is Scrapy not synchronous

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to override Scrapy's `start_requests` method, but unsuccessful. I'm already fine to iterate through pages. The problem is that now I have to iterate firstly through cities and than pages.

My code looks like this:

```
URL = "https://example.com/%s/?page=%d"
starting_number = 1
number_of_pages = 3
cities = [] # there are array of cities
selected_city = "..."

def start_requests(self):
    for city in cities:
        selected_city = city

        print "####################"
        print "##### CITY: " + selected_city + " #####"

        for i in range(self.page_number, number_of_pages, +1):
            print "##### page: " + str(i) + " #####"
            yield scrapy.Request(url=(URL % (selected_city, i)), callback = self.parse)

        print "####################"
```

In console I see that when crawler starts working it prints all cities and pages, and than only start requests. Therefore as the result my crawler parses only the first city. They work asynchronously, while I need synchronous.

What is the right way to iterate in my case?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: did you try replacing `yield` with `return` ?

Comment: No. My problem was that I used wrongly global variable `selected_city` in the remaining code.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I used wrongly global variable `selected_city` in the remaining code.

I thought that on every iteration it would stop to do `parse` method, and than continue to next iteration. Therefore I set parameter `item['city'] = selected_city` in `parse` method.

Now I just pass parameter `city` through `Request`'s meta parameter.
Sample code:

```
def start_requests(self):
    requests = []

    for city in cities:
        for i in range(self.page_number, number_of_pages, +1):
            requests.append(scrapy.Request(url=(URL % (city, i)), callback = self.parse, meta = {'city': city}))

    return requests
```

And in `parse` method retrieving by doing: `item['city'] = response.request.meta['city']`